# Is there a way to see how many ssh slave connections are open under a master ssh connection?

Tags: ssh

I'd like to see how many slave connections I have under a master ssh connection. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "slave connections", you mean connections created using ControlMaster, you can run `lsof -U | grep $WHATEVER_YOUR_CONTROLPATH_IS` and count the number of connections to the socket.

`lsof -U` gives you a list of Unix domain sockets, which will include all the ssh processes using the control socket created by ControlMaster.

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the controlpath?

Comment: I believe you have to set it in your ssh configuration (take a look at `man ssh_config` for the details), or using the -S option on the command line (see `man ssh`)

Answer (score 0):

The connections are opened as a `channels` in the single TCP connection, therefore you can use escape sequence `~#` inside the `ssh` session. It will list all of the channels, where you can simply identify the sessions, port forwardings, X11 forwadings and so on. For example:

```
[server ~]# ~#
The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 5/6 cc -1)
```